# App Engine Multiple Email Addresses Returns 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, handler

I am trying to process inbound emails (on dev server) sent to different addresses like:

```
- url: /_ah/jogo@.*rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
script: jogo.py

- url: /_ah/contato@.*rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
script: contato.py

- url: /.*
script: helloworld.py
```

but I get the following log message:

```
INFO     2012-07-27 20:05:31,759 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /_ah/mail/jogo@rpg2e.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I also tried:

```
- url: /_ah/jogo@rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
script: jogo.py

- url: /_ah/contato@rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
script: contato.py

- url: /.*
script: helloworld.py
```

to no avail.

If I simply use a handle_all it works like a charm, but I would like my script only to handle email sent to the correct handle@rpg2e.appspotmail.com

After spending some time searching the Web and within Stack Overflow, I came across many questions like mine, and the only working solution was to use the catch all approach. Some of them were even answered by Ikai Lane[1] with the same conclusion - only catch all works.

Then again, did anyone have success using multiple handlers?

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/UGTkMV9foJ0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Google App Engine Python - Receiving Mail](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail)

```
url: /_ah/mail/owner@.*your_app_id\.appspotmail\.com 
  script: handle_owner.py 
  login: admin
- url: /_ah/mail/support@.*your_app_id\.appspotmail\.com 
  script: handle_support.py 
  login: admin
```

You are missing the `/mail/` portion of the required path. You're POSTING to `/_ah/jogo@rpg2e.appspotmail.com` instead of `/_ah/mail/jogo@rpg2e.appspotmail.com`. Try this instead:

```
- url: /_ah/mail/jogo@rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
  script: jogo.py

- url: /_ah/mail/contato@rpg2e\.appspotmail\.com
  script: contato.py
```

Lastly, we all get a little tunnel vision every now and then when confronted with a problem, but it's worth noting the value in error messages. The error message tells us *where* App Engine is looking when it makes the POST request, which you could match up with your handlers:

```
INFO   2012-07-27 20:05:31,759 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST /_ah/mail/jogo@rpg2e.appspotmail.com HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a little bit embarassing to see the solution was so simple and crystal clear. I suppose i overlooked the log message, but i confirm your modification worked.

Sorry to bother, but am i required to mark the problem solved?

Comment: Like I said, we *all* get tunnel vision every now and then. I felt it would be incomplete not to highlight the importance of error messages though, in case a passerby may learn from that. Good luck with your project! :)